# Speech recognition in Windows application

Tags: c#, windows, speech-recognition

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    Grammar dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
    recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);
    try
    {
        button1.Text = "speak now";
        recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();
        textBox1.Text = result.Text;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
    {
        textBox1.Text = String.Format("Could not recognize input from default audio device.Is a microphone or sound card available?\r\n{0} - {1}.", exception.Source, exception.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        recognizer.UnloadAllGrammars();
    }
}
```

Here it is not recognizing the exact word what am giving from microphone.It s taking another word,which is not meaningfull. How to rectify this problem?

Comment: You should try initializing your `SpeechRecognitionEngine` with your language culture. See the [sample code from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554580(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples).

Comment: Please specify more details like- 3rd party libraries, input/output. There is brief an MSDN article on this-https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Actually in thisRecognitionResult result=recognizer.Recognize()

Comment: when i debug this,in  result.Alternates it is taking default values in array format...it is not recognizing properly

Comment: plz resolve the problem

Comment: @Khanna what problem? You didn't specify enough information (engine, libraries etc). It could be something as simple as having a strong accent.

Comment: In this i used system.speech ,system.speech.Recognition and speech recognitionEngine what else should i use ??